# Como quitar lineas en blanco en documento PDF Angular?

Tags: typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

> Hola amigos tengo un problema al generar un archivo PDF me coloca una linea en blanco en algunas filas de los textos, cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando con angular y la libreria de jspdf y html2canvas.

[image: documento pdf pero se coloca una linea en blanco]

este es el codigo que tengo en el componente ts:

```
 const DATA = document.getElementById('htmlData');
const customWidth = 595; // Ancho en puntos (por ejemplo, para tamaño A4)
const customHeight = 845; 
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [customWidth, customHeight]);
const options = {
  background: 'white',
  scale: 3,
  autoSize: true,
};

let yOffset = 15; // Posición vertical inicial
const pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;

const pdf = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/PNG');
  const imgProps = (doc as any).getImageProperties(imgData);
  const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 2 * 10; // Margen izquierdo y derecho de 10
  const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
   
  if (yOffset + pdfHeight > pageHeight) {
    doc.addPage();
    yOffset = 15;
  }

  doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 15, yOffset, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
  yOffset += pdfHeight + 10;
};

// Utiliza html2canvas para convertir el contenido en múltiples imágenes
html2canvas(DATA, options).then((canvas) => {
  const contentHeight = canvas.height;
  const numPages = Math.ceil(contentHeight / pageHeight);

  let page = 0;
  let yPos = 0;

  while (page < numPages) {
    const canvasClone = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvasClone.width = canvas.width;
    canvasClone.height = Math.min(pageHeight, contentHeight - yPos);

    const ctx = canvasClone.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, yPos, canvasClone.width, canvasClone.height, 0, 0, canvasClone.width, canvasClone.height);

    pdf(canvasClone);

    yPos += canvasClone.height;
    page++;
  } 
  doc.save('documento.pdf');
});
```

Y en el HTML este es mi codigo:

```
     <form id="htmlData" action="#">
                            
                            <p style="font-size:24px;font-family:Arial;text-align: justify;width:90%;margin:0em auto;"> 
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam soluta fugit dolorem ab illo excepturi delectus enim dolorum ex nostrum, omnis eveniet dolores blanditiis accusamus maxime dolore atque ducimus alias.
                            </p><br/>

                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                                <h3>lorem</h3>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div style="font-size:24px;font-family:Arial;text-align: start;width:90%;margin:0em auto;">
                               <div>"La Empresa" manifiesta:</div>  
                               <ol>
                                    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, odit tenetur quis corporis iure dolore voluptate unde accusantium sunt harum ex. Repellat sint aperiam totam impedit atque mollitia quae at..</li>
                                    
                                </ol>
                                 
                            </div>
                                     
                               

                            

                            
                            
                        </form>
```

> estube modificando la altura y lo que logre fue que si lo quita pero extiende demasiado la hoja y no es lo optimo deberia de tener un tamaño definido y si ya no cabe el contenido en la primer hoja agregar dinamicamente la siguiente, si me pudieran orientar que parametros debo corregir de antemano gracias.